Issue with InteractiveViewer in Flutter: Part of the Map is Cut Off
I am working on an interactive map in Flutter using InteractiveViewer, but I am encountering an issue where only a portion of the map is visible. The rest is cut off, and I see the red background color of the container instead. It seems like InteractiveViewer or the underlying Stack is not rendering the full map correctly.
Here’s the code I’m using:
return Container(
  color: Colors.red,
  alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
  child: InteractiveViewer(
    transformationController: controller,
    minScale: 0.0001,
    maxScale: 1000,
    scaleFactor: 0.5,
    constrained: true,
    child: Builder(builder: (context) {
      WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
        final childSize = context.size ?? Size.zero;
        print('Container size: $childSize');

        if (childSize == Size.zero) return;

        var scaleFactor = _coverRatio(widget.globalBounds.size, childSize);
        print('Scale factor: $scaleFactor');

        var translationX = (childSize.width - (widget.globalBounds.width * scaleFactor)) / 2;
        controller.value = Matrix4.identity()
          ..scale(scaleFactor)
          ..translate(translationX);
      });
      return Stack(
        children: [
          for (var element in widget.officeElements)
            _getClippedImage(
              clipper: ClipperWidget(
                svgPath: element.path,
                transform: element.transform,
              ),
              color: Color(int.parse('FF${element.color}', radix: 16)),
              element: element,
              onElementSelected: widget.onElementSelected,
            ),
        ],
      );
    }),
  ),
);

Helper Functions:
double _coverRatio(Size svgSize, Size containerSize) {
  final widthRatio = containerSize.width / svgSize.width;
  final heightRatio = containerSize.height / svgSize.height;
  return widthRatio < heightRatio ? widthRatio : heightRatio;
}

Widget _getClippedImage({
  required ClipperWidget clipper,
  required Color color,
  required OfficeElement element,
  required final Function(DeskReservation deskReservation) onElementSelected,
}) {
  return Stack(
    children: [
      ClipPath(
        clipper: clipper,
        child: Container(
          color: color,
        ),
      ),
      Positioned(
        left: element.bounds.topLeft.dx,
        top: element.bounds.topLeft.dy,
        child: SizedBox(
          width: element.bounds.width,
          height: element.bounds.height,
          child: _getEntityWidget(element, onElementSelected),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  );
}

Problem:
When I view the map, only a portion of it is visible. The rest is cut off, and the red background of the container is shown. I suspect that InteractiveViewer or the underlying Stack is not handling the rendering correctly.
Attempts to Resolve:
I tried using MyLayoutDelegate, and in this case, I was able to see the entire base of the map, but the elements were not visible.
I verified that the container’s size is correct and there are no issues with its definition.
Question:
What could be causing this issue with InteractiveViewer, and how can I resolve it to ensure that the entire map is visible?
Thank you in advance for your help!
